# Save output of "conda activate env_name" to variable in a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, variables, cmd, conda

I want to save the output of the command "*conda activate env_name*" into a variable in a batch file to determine whether or not I need to create a new environment for a script on my device.

I have tried to following code where I save the variable as output it and echo it back out:

```
for /f %%i in ('call conda activate env_name') do set output=%%i
echo %output%
```

However, this returns:

```
%output%
```

I have tried it with various other forms of output, including *%output* and *%%output*. I believe the variable isn't being set at all because when I use *set output=i* it echoes *i* instead.

Similarly, I have had some luck with saving the output to a file instead.

```
'conda activate env_name' 2>> "temp.txt"
set /p OUTPUT=<"temp.txt"
echo %OUTPUT%
```

Where this time the text file and echoing the variable output returns the below:

```
''conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

This is not result I am looking for however. Usually when I manually run the command I see the message below, and this is the output I am hoping to have saved to a variable:

```
Could not find conda environment: env_name
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Comment: the command is `conda`, not `'conda`. The single quotes are only used in the `for /f` command. Have you tried `for /f %%i in ('call conda activate env_name 2^>^&1') do set output=%%i` ?

Comment: @Stephan That is a lot closer, it looks like it is storing the output as the first word in the last line now!

Comment: Yes, the last line. `for /f` processes each non-empty line, so it overwrites the variable again and again, and leaves you with the last line. Use `delims=` to get the whole line (see `for /?` to learn more). `2>&1` redirects STDERR to the same destination as STDOUT, which enables `for /f` to catch it too.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need `for`: `call conda activate env_name 2>&1 |find "Could not find conda environment" && echo no such env` - of course this depends on your intentions.